# OpenCV - Access to pixels along the curve/path

Tags: c++, opencv

is there any way to access pixels along the specified curve/path in OpenCV?

I've found LineIterator:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=lineiterator#LineIterator
but it's limited to lines. I would like to find something similar to LineIterator, but working with circles, since I need to read the pixels along the circle, or ellipse.

Comment: if the curve/path is parameterizable, you can try my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590329/access-to-pixels-along-the-curve-path-using-opencv/20710629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not builtin to opencv, but you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm for circles, the article also mentions a paper that describes an extention to ellipses.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will have to implement it by myself. The Wiki explanation isn't quite good. It's better to use the implementation and explanation from here: http://free.pages.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html